# Remove some field from nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example I have a dict:

```
{
    "a" : 123,
    "b" : {
        "a" : 24324,
        "c" : 9
    },
    "c" : {
        "a" : 123,
        "b" : 64
    }
}
```

What is the best way to remove all `a` fields from this dictionary? I understand, that I can do an iteration over this dict, remove `a` field, that iterate on the keys, which are also dicts and so on.

But maybe there is more elegant way to do it?

**EDIT**
Thanks for your answers! But what about a situation, when keys can be lists, like `"b" : [{"a" : 1, "c" : 2}]`

Comment: There is not. you have to create a recursive function to do that.

Comment: that would be enough, a recursive function would be pretty sort and elegant too, but maybe slow, its up to you.

Comment: See the edit to my answer regarding lists nested in dicts

Answer (score 2):

Well, internally you have to process the items one by one, either by manual iteration or recursion.

Here's an attempt using recursion:

```
def remove_keys(d, to_remove):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return {k: remove_keys(v, to_remove)
            for k, v in d.items() if k not in to_remove}
```

You would simply pass the dictionary to process as the first argument and the name of the keys to remove (as a `set`, preferably) as the second argument. In your case:

```
remove_keys(d, {"a"})
```

Whether it's more elegant or not, it depends on your taste, I would  say :).

If you want to actually mutate the dictionary:

```
def remove_keys_m(d, to_remove):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    for k in to_remove:
        if k in d:
            del d[k]
    for k in d:
            d[k] = remove_keys(d[k], to_remove)
    return d
```

Comment: you are not filtering the dict, but actually returning a new one

Comment: I updated your question adding a mutable version of your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_entries(d, k):
    if k in d:
        del d[k]
    for value in d.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            remove_entries(value, k)
```

Here's a pretty basic recursive function for doing it

Edit:

If you also want to handle lists nested in dicts, nested in lists, etc, something like the below will owrk.

```
def remove_from_dict_in_list(l, k):
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            remove_from_dict_in_list(i, k)
        elif isinstance(i, dict):
            remove_entries(i, k)

def remove_entries(d, k):
    if k in d:
        del d[k]
    for value in d.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            remove_entries(value, k)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            remove_from_dict_in_list(value, k)
```

Comment: Why use `try/except` if a sinple `if` is only two lines instead of four?

Answer (score 0):

While a recursive solution is more robust, here is a simpler solution that will work for the posted example and any other dictionary with only one nested layer:

```
s = {
   "a" : 123,
   "b" : {
     "a" : 24324,
     "c" : 9
   },
  "c" : {
       "a" : 123,
      "b" : 64
  }
} 

final_data = {a:{c:d for c, d in b.items() if c != "a"} for a, b in s.items() if a != "a"}
```

Output:

```
{'c': {'b': 64}, 'b': {'c': 9}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will answer your question.

```
dic = {"a": 1,
       "b": {"a": 2,
             "c": {"a": 3}},
       "d": 4}
key_to_del = "a"

def get_key(dic):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if key == key_to_del:
            del dic[key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            get_key(value)
    return dic

print "BEFOR", dic
print "AFTER", get_key(dic)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obznu.png)